# Column name from sql query in php

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I am trying to extract a column name from SQL database to use in a dropdown in HTML. I am then trying to insert PHP into the HTML dropdown to display column name.

I have used fetch array to get output from SQL using a variable from another drop down to pull the relevant SQL table. However i can't return the column name in PHP. All I get is the value using `$row[2].`

Is there an easy way to pull the column name (i.e. the non-numeric value in square brackets after the numerical value).

```
$query="SELECT * FROM ".($units_cat)."";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        echo nl2br (" \n Query was successful \n");
        print_r($row);
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<option value="<?php $row[2]?>"
        <?php 
        if($_POST['units_from']==$row) 
            echo 'selected="selected"';?>
        >
<?php echo ($row[2])?>
</option>
```

**OUTPUT FROM SQL QUERY**

```
Array ( 
   [0] => 1 
        [id] => 1 
   [1] => Klbs 
        [from_value] => Klbs 
   [2] => 1.0000000000 
        [klbs] => 1.0000000000 
  [3] => 1000.0000000000 
        [pound] => 1000.0000000000 
  [4] => 0.4535923700 
        [ton] => 0.4535923700 
  [5] => 453.5923700000 
        [kg] => 453.5923700000 
  [6] => 224.8089424432 
        [newton] => 224.8089424432 
  [7] => 22.4808942443 
         [dn] => 22.4808942443 
  [8] => 0.2248089424 
         [kn] => 0.2248089424 
    )
```

Comment: Try `mysqli_fetch_assoc` or add `MYSQLI_ASSOC` to your [fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) (see the docs), and you'll be able to get just the column->values. Now, as far as getting all of the column names, you can use a foreach to get the key/value.

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks with that code, whenever you plug a value into a query ***ALWAYS*** use a prepared statement, no matter what the source of the data that's being plugging into the query

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by using DESCRIBE to output array of table data. Then create an array of the columns.

```
 $query2=("DESCRIBE ".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $units_cat));

if ($result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2)) {
    $table_desc = mysqli_fetch_all($result2);


#Create an array of column values   
    foreach($table_desc as $val) {  
        $col[]=$val[0]; 
    }
```

Then call the column values in the relevant dropdown.

```
 <option value="<?php echo($col[2]) ?>"<?php if($_POST['units_from']==($col[2])) echo 
 'selected="selected"';?>><?php echo($col[2]) ?></option>
```

I had to white-list the tables that $units_cat was referencing as I believe you cannot prepare a table as you are unable to bind parameters to a table entry in PHP/SQL.

```
#Get tables list for whitelisting
$query3="Show tables";
$result3=mysqli_query($link,$query3);

if (!$result3) {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error();
    exit;
}

if ($result3=mysqli_query($link,$query3)){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result3)){

        $tables[]=$row[0];

    }
}       


#UNITS CAT WHITELIST CHECK  
if (in_array($units_cat,$tables)){

    echo nl2br (" \n Units Cat Table exists");

}else{

    echo "Table does not exist";
    mysqli_close($link);
    echo "<br>";
    die("non valid entry");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

with mysql_fetch_array you can access each parameter individually
$row['id'];
$row['pound'];

However, storing the different values for a same variable (in kg, in tons , in...) in the database seems a bit unnecessary taking into account that you can save the space with a simple conversion using the metric unit. do your users need to input the weight in different units each time?

Comment: Yes they will put different units in as it is a units converter. I want to be able to call the parameter name using the sequence in the array and not the parameter name. This is because the parameter will change depending on the selection on another drop-down. (i.e. the array shown is for MASS when I select the next dropdown- FLOW the parameter value will change to flow values such as GPM)

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions.